# Is it possible to filter and bring back only one of each notificationType/postId?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `notification` `model` with this `Schema` here:

```
const NotificationSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  postId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'post',
    required: true
  },
  recipients: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
    required: true
  }]
});
```

I'm building a route controller that will get all `notifications` where they are one of the `recipients` here:

```
getNotifications(req, res, next) {
    const userId = req.params.id;

    Notification.find({ recipients: userId })
      .sort({ createdAt: 1 })
      .then(notifications => res.send(notifications))
      .catch(next);
  },
```

I also want to make sure that if there are several `notifications` that have the same `type`, such as `postAuthorNotification` AND the same `postId`, then it only brings back the `notification` that has the latest `createdAt` `timestamp`.

The reason for this is that if a users' post gets commented on 20 times. There will be a `notification` for each. I only want to send the user back ONE notification though, the latest one.

Is this possible at all with mongo/mongoose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the `.sort()` method chained, which should give you results sorted by `createdAt`. To limit to only 1 result, simply chain a `.limit(1)` to the query.

Official documentation for the `limit` method - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit